# Trying to retrieve value of checked radio button's previous sibling's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here's something i'm struggling with. Below is the html for a single color swatch. on this page there may be hundreds of color swatches. there will be a default value, a checked radio button once the page loads.

what i'm trying to retrieve is, and put into a variable is
the value of the checked input that is a sibling of, and before and is of type hidden (i've marked with comment)

in all the examples i looked at in retrieving values of checked radio buttons, 
did not consider that name is part of an array and name accordingly ie.

*$('input[name=id[]]:checked') .. and this does not work.*

```
<div class="color-swatch-wrapper">
<input type="hidden" name="descriptive[9]" value="SL01"  class="swatch-descriptive-name" /><!-- trying to retrieve this value -->
<input type="radio" name="id[9]" value="70" checked="checked" id="attrib-9-70" class="threads-radio-btn" />
<label class="attribsRadioButton two thread-opts" for="attrib-9-70">SL01<br />
   <img src="images/attributes/SL01.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="320" />
</label>
</div>
```

my pseudo code would read something like:

```
descriptiveName = ($('input[name=id[]]:checked', '#nameOfForm').prev.().val())
```

where prev is the sibling before that contains the descriptive name value.
big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are tring to find element named exactly "id[]"...

To give desired result you can find element with names starting from "id[":

```
$('input[name^="id["]:checked').prev().val()
```